# sum of two normally distributed random variables

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBZDN.png)I know the theorem that the sum of two independent normally distributed random variables is normal, with its mean being the sum of the two means, and its variance being the sum of the two variances. But when I look through the proof of this theorem on wikipedia, i find there's something hard for me to understand. Based on what I have learned so far, I can only use the convolution formula to complete this proof. Everything goes smoothly except for the last step. Suppose Z is X+Y.
I can't figure out why the integral on the right side is 1. I don't understand how each part of this integral corresponds to the basic form of the normal distribution.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are referring to this proof:
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables

This is a common trick in probability. To convince yourself, take the object they claim integrates to 1 and “spell it out” as a normal density function. To do this, remember a normal density function will have some variance $\tilde{\sigma}$ and mean $\tilde{\mu}$. Define these variance and mean in order for the expression to look “simpler”, the variance $\tilde{\sigma}$ will need to be a ratio of the variance of $X$ times the variance of $Y$, and the variance of $Z$.

Define a new normal random variable $W$,(because, why can’t you do that? I can take any real number $>0$ and call that the variance of a new random variable and any real number, even zero or negative, and call that the mean) with variance $\tilde{\sigma}$ and mean $\tilde{\mu}$ and write down the property that if you integrate over the whole of the real numbers the density of $W$ gives you 1.

Give it a shot and if you need more help send a comment.

Comment: i have substituted some special values, and it's amazing that the  really corresponds to . The integral really gives 1. But i'm still not sure about my heart that i want to prove this kind of correspondence if possible. Can you give me some more help?

Comment: (1) Write down the special values here of your mean and variance. (2) Define a normal random variable to have that mean and variance. (3) Write down what it means for this new normal random variable’s density function to integrate to 1

Comment: I get your point, thank u!!